# Discard older elements in Django queryset

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have a list of elements on my database, and each one has its own datetime field. I want to discard the elements that are older than today, meaning that I will only see the future ones.

This is my current code:

```
def get_dates_approved(request):
    user = request.user
    alreadyRated = [x.date.id for x in Ratings.objects.filter(rator=user)]
    dates = Dating.objects.filter((Q(creator=user) | Q(assignee=user)) & Q(accepted=True)) \
                      .exclude(id__in=alreadyRated)
    return dates
```

And the field that defines the date is this one:

```
finalDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django queryset has field lookups.

From the Django docs,

> Field lookups are how you specify the meat of an SQL WHERE clause. They’re specified as keyword arguments to the QuerySet methods filter(), exclude() and get().

There are a number of built-in lookups available such as `exact`, `iexact`, `contains`, `gt`, `gte`, `lt`, `lte` and many more. For more info, please refer to [Django queryset field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#field-lookups).

To answer your question

```
dates = Dating.objects.filter((Q(creator=user) | Q(assignee=user)) & Q(accepted=True)) \
                  .exclude(id__in=alreadyRated)
```

should be

```
dates = Dating.objects.filter((Q(creator=user) | Q(assignee=user)) & Q(accepted=True)) \
                  .exclude(id__in=alreadyRated, finalDate__lt=datetime.today())
```

so your function should look like

```
from datetime import datetime

def get_dates_approved(request):
    user = request.user
    alreadyRated = [x.date.id for x in Ratings.objects.filter(rator=user)]
    dates = Dating.objects.filter((Q(creator=user) | Q(assignee=user)) & Q(accepted=True)) \
                      .exclude(id__in=alreadyRated, finalDate__lt=datetime.today())
```